# Connecting to and running programs on a PC from totally separate PCs

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

This probably seems ridiculously simple compared to normal here, but I was wondering how I could run a program from a separate PC on a separate internet connection? Running one on the same internet is easy, with `wmic /node:(IP Address here) process call create "c:\windows\notepad.exe"` for example. I could not, however, find a single site that could tell me how, so I posted this. All I want is a way to allow myself to interact with a program I'll want to be able to allow my friends to remotely start and backup from they're own PCs. The interaction, however I have covered. The problem is actually contacting the PC from various PCs and WiFis, preferably without downloading anything (recently got a virus because I was distracted, and am a little nervous now) but will download if necessary...

Comment: Are you aware of [SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) ? To run any program remotely you need some kind of server.

Comment: I was more hoping for a way to send a file that could be double-clicked or something to the people I want to give access, but that works too, I guess. Might be able to get a good system working with that though. Thanks.

Comment: What make you think that every computer has a desktop interface? On my computer, most programs are started with a command line. For example, most web servers usually don't. Your question is not a programming question so is off-topic here. It might fit better on https://superuser.com/

Comment: Where'd you get that idea from? I was talking about sending the file to people I want to be able to start, backup, or change a program running on my pc.

Comment: Sending a file to someone is really easy. In many cases, you might make it an attachment in some email. Or you could use FTP or HTTP protocols. Or some `scp` command (related to SSH). How (and if) your recipient uses that file is his problem, not yours. He could double-click, run a command, transfer that to another computer, etc.

Comment: You're seriously not getting my point. That's easy. What I want is a method of making that file so it can actually affect my pc. Example: I double click on a file, and that file causes another computer on a completely different network to backup a program and send a copy back to the first computer without anyone being within 50 miles of the server computer running the program that was backed up.

Comment: But why the double click? Why not more simply use the [command line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface)? If you are asking to run some command remotely, there are lots of solutions, notably [SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell). No double-cliking is necessary. (I never double-click to run programs on my Linux desktop). And your friends could also use the command line. Your question looks like some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). What is the actual issue that you are having? Show some [MCVE]

Comment: Because the people who I'd sent the double-clicked file to know nothing about programming. They just use what basic programs I'm capable of making, and doing that would be beyond their capabilities. Making a double-click-able file seemed the best solution.

Comment: Ok, to simplify this a whole lot, what I need is a way to make an executable file run a program on a separate pc on a separate network with minimal downloads (preferably just the file itself) for the client.

Comment: That sentence is completely confusing. You could code a program which uses remote service (by some kind of [remote procedure call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) for example). You could install a web server on your PC, and ask your friends to use it (and make your web server do dynamic things, like most of them do). Your question is really lacking some [MCVE]

Comment: Also, I can program. The problem is, I couldn't find a single thing on this particular subject with a simple enough solution for a practical usage in my case. I can figure a lot of stuff out normally, but connecting like this isn't really simple.

Comment: What subject? Remote execution exists since several dozen of years. You should think more in terms of protocols when you want some remote things to happen

Comment: You know what, I'm probably just being stupid at this point...

Comment: You have an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). Your question is unclear. For example, if several machines are involved, name them (by stating first: my PC is `computera`, my friend's PC is `computerb`, etc..). Then describe the protocols that you use (HTTP, SSH, ....), the communication that happens (what file is sent, from what source to what destination computer, how; what connections are made by various programs), and the effect you want them to have.

Comment: I'm feeling that you might install some HTTP server on your own machine, and ask your friends to access it with their browser (or write for them some program doing HTTP, perhaps thru an HTTP client library such as [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/). Why is such a [web service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) solution not acceptable?

Comment: For this example my computer = server, and my friend's computer = client. I want help figuring out how to make a program that when executed on the client produces an effect on the server by running a .bat file which does whatever.

Comment: A web service would work too, I guess. I just have no clue as to what I'm doing, as usual.

Comment: What is the real life problem you want to solve? Why do you need your friends to make some effect on your computer? Which effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I could simply make a discord bot that runs my .bat on demand from anywhere... Well, thanks anyway for your attempted help!